# Difference between reading speed from a memory create with CL_MEM_READ_WRITE and CL_MEM_READ flags

Tags: opencl

In my project in the first stage, I generate some vertices then in second stage I read these vertices and then create connectivity array. For my vertices I have used CL_MEM_READ_WRITE. I wanted to know will I have a performance increase if I use a CL_WRITE memory in the first stage then copy it in another CL_READ memory for the second stage? Because probably each of them has its own optimization to get the maximum performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not. I expect the buffer copy to be far more costly than any optimization.

Also, I looked at the AMD APP OpenCL Programming Guide and I didn't find any indication about optimizations when using a `READ_ONLY` or `WRITE_ONLY` buffer.

My understanding is that the access flag is only used by the OpenCL runtime to decide when it needs to copy buffer data between the different memory spaces/areas.

Comment: But anyway it is good to try because I experience a very big difference between read only and read-write memories in directx 11. Also, I was thinking it something similar to opengl's STATIC/DYNAMIC which the STATIC one is pretty faster than the DYNAMIC one.

Comment: You will only see a benefit when you have 2 or 3 GPUs working on the same data. OpenCL can use the knowledge to not trigger memory consistency copy between devices, therefore increasing the overall speed. But that will not be the applicable for single GPU case.

Answer (score 3):

The flag passed in the 2nd argument Of CL_CREATEBUFER only specifies how the kernel side can access the memory space.